# VirtualBox not starting: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: virtualbox, qt5

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 using default gnome desktop.

When I try to launch VirtualBox it does not load. When I run it from the terminal I get an error message:

```
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain:
dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: 
libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can see that libqt5 is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libqt5
ii  libqt5core5a:amd64                         5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 core module
ii  libqt5dbus5:amd64                          5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 D-Bus module
ii  libqt5designer5:amd64                      5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 designer module
ii  libqt5gui5:amd64                           5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 GUI module
ii  libqt5help5:amd64                          5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 help module
ii  libqt5multimedia5:amd64                    5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 Multimedia module
ii  libqt5network5:amd64                       5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 network module
ii  libqt5opengl5:amd64                        5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 OpenGL module
ii  libqt5positioning5:amd64                   5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2                    amd64        Qt Positioning module
ii  libqt5printsupport5:amd64                  5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 print support module
ii  libqt5qml5:amd64                           5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 QML module
ii  libqt5quick5:amd64                         5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 Quick library
ii  libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64               5.9.5-0ubuntu2                         amd64        Qt 5 Quick Controls 2 library
ii  libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64              5.9.5-0ubuntu2                         amd64        Qt 5 Quick Templates 2 library
ii  libqt5quickwidgets5:amd64                  5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 Quick Widgets library
ii  libqt5script5:amd64                        5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 script module
ii  libqt5sensors5:amd64                       5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt Sensors module
ii  libqt5sql5:amd64                           5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 SQL module
ii  libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64                    5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libqt5svg5:amd64                           5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 SVG module
ii  libqt5test5:amd64                          5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 test module
ii  libqt5texttospeech5:amd64                  5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Speech library for Qt - libraries
ii  libqt5waylandclient5:amd64                 5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        QtWayland client library
ii  libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64             5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        QtWayland compositor library
ii  libqt5webchannel5:amd64                    5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Web communication library for Qt
ii  libqt5webkit5:amd64                        5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1                amd64        Web content engine library for Qt
ii  libqt5widgets5:amd64                       5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 widgets module
ii  libqt5x11extras5:amd64                     5.9.5-0ubuntu1                         amd64        Qt 5 X11 extras
ii  libqt5xml5:amd64                           5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Qt 5 XML module
```

---

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so | grep not
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
```

---

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 | grep not
ldd: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: No such file or directory
```

Virtualbox was installed through the Software Centre.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/virtualbox
virtualbox-qt: /usr/bin/virtualbox
```

---

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core*
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core*': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of the following commands: `ldd /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so | grep not` and `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 | grep not` to show missed libraries. How did you install VirtualBox (add output of `dpkg -S /usr/bin/virtualbox` to the question)?

Comment: Just to be sure, what does `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core*` say?